# What's a quicker way to pass a user input into a parameter of a classes function?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to pass input without creating a variable for `cin` to work with and then having to pass that variable into the parameter of the classes function just so it all can look a little bit cleaner:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Customer.cpp"
#include "Customer.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Customer object;

    int num;

    cout << "Enter a number to be archived: ";
    cin >> num;

    object.setNum(num); //I don't want to have to do this

    num = object.getNum();

    cout << num;
}
```

Comment: Could you add a method to the `Customer` class that handles the IO/setting?

Comment: So you write a `Customer::getnuminput()` function that will prompt the user and read the input for you. You can also do that in the constructor if a `num` parameter isn't passed to initialize `num` when the object is created.

Comment: IMO getting input isn't part of a `Customer`. Input wrangling can be handled in a class/utility, but I personally encourage separation of concerns.

Answer (score 0):

Two things here:

You can use a constructor for Customer:

```
int num;
cout << "Enter a number to be archived: ";
cin >> num;

Customer object(num);
num = object.getNum();

cout << num;
```

If this still doesn't work for you, show a way how you want to code look like so that we could show you how to manage this.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to implement `operator>>` and `operator<<` for `Customer`, eg:

```cpp
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream &in, Customer &c)
{
    int num;
    if (cin >> num)
        c.setNum(num);
    return in;
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &out, const Customer &c)
{
    return out << c.getNum();
}
```

Then you can do this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
//#include "Customer.cpp" // <-- DON'T #include .cpp files!
#include "Customer.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Customer object;
    cout << "Enter a number to be archived: ";
    cin >> object;
    cout << object;
}
```